# Django: CSRF check only when certain conditions apply

Tags: django, authentication, csrf

I have a simple REST API that needs to be accessible both from a web app as well as from a remote service.

The remote service is authenticated via a custom HTTP header containing an API key.

How can I protect that API such that requests from a web browser are CSRF protected, but the CSRF check is not done when authenticated via API key? Or, in general, how can I enable CSRF protection for some requests on a specific view, but not others?

Currently, I have a decorator that checks the request for an API key and authenticates the API user roughly this way:

```
# Regular auth
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    # DO CSRF verification, then continue calling the view

elif 'HTTP_X_API_KEY' in request.META:
    api_key = request.META['HTTP_X_API_KEY']
    user = authenticate(username=settings.API_USER_NAME, password=api_key)
    login(request, user)
    # If user is authenticated and autzorized, continue calling the view
    # but WITHOUT invoking CSRF protection
```

The problem as stated is, that I only want CSRF protection for regular users, but not for the API user.

Comment: You could override the csrf middleware and do the same check in there. That way you won't have to keep track of views that need protection.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after a bit more of tinkering around, the solution was to disable the CSRF middleware and enable `csrf_protect` for all cases where CSRF protection is required.

This works in the special case of the API, as every call is being decorated anyway, so the risk of some view being forgotten is negligible.

What does **not** work however, is the other way around, using `csrf_exempt`. The problem there is that the decorator only sets a `csrf_exempt` property on the view, which, if you have multiple decorators, may be masked again, even if you use `functools.wraps`.

Also, since `csrf_exempt` puts a property on the view, it cannot be dynamically enabled or disabled based on the request's content - it's really a very static thing to do.